# Am I doing it right? Background work in Windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows forms application. I want to do something in background after pressing some button.

```
//---------- MyWorker::Run
public Task Run()
{
   WorkerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       //Access MyWorker's properties etc. causes complications as it runs from 
       // a different thread and I need to use InvokeRequired etc. but not everything has Invoke method implemented.
   }, TokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

   return WorkerTask;
}

//---------- Form event
async void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var task = MyWorker.Run();

   await task;
}
```

However there are some complications when I try to access MyWorker's objects in the run method as it runs in a different thread. What pattern would be prefered here? I was thinking about something like:

```
//---------- Form event
async void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       var MyWorker1 = new MyWorker(...);
       // Worker is synchronous here
       MyWorker1.Run();
   }, TokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

But I wouldn't be able to access MyWorker from other methods. Thanks in advance .. I'm confused.

Comment: The question is not clear. Is `Run` a static method? Are you trying to access some UI elements from the `Run` method? How does the `Run` method have access to any UI elements?

Comment: Run is not a static method. I'm trying to access MyWorker's elements from run method. I've got events in MyWorker class like OnRunning, OnFinished etc. and I register them within my UI form to update the progress.

Comment: What do you mean "elements"? Is `MyWorker` a form?

Comment: I mean data members. MyWorker is not a form but a data member of a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't *implement* a method entirely in terms of `Task.Run` (or `StartNew`); instead, *call* the method with `Task.Run`:

```
async void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var task = Task.Run(() => MyWorker.Run());
  await task;
}
```

This way you can access `MyWorker` from multiple methods... and multiple threads, of course. It's up to you to apply appropriate synchronization then.

On a side note, you shouldn't ever need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` in modern apps; there are always superior solutions. For example, `await` will return to the UI thread context automatically. Similarly, `Progress<T>` can synchronize to the UI context automatically.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know. But what if inside Task.Run MyWorker.Run() is called from a different thread than one it was created on. Will it cause crashes? 
I have MyWorker data member and then I do MyWorker.Run() from different thread.

Comment: Also I want to cancel MyWorker if it's possible so I need to throw inside MyWorker.Run... So I don't think it will do the trick.

Comment: @Konrad: That totally depends on how `MyWorker` is implemented. Cancellation works perfectly fine with `Task.Run`; any exceptions are propagated through the `await`.

Comment: I have a loop in MyWorker.run and it checks each iteration if cancellation was requested. How would I achieve it with your pattern ?

Comment: @Konrad You should pass `CancellationToken` to `MyWorker.Run`

Comment: @IvanStoev I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can customize this approach:

```
var myTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
var myResults = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
```

and use it like:

```
myTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //do something
    myResults.Add(5);
});
```

Comment: for change the UI object use '@Eduardo Wada's answer